# jquery not able to get value from a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I am trying to get a value from a hidden field. I am using the code

```
function foo(){
 alert($('#idhere').val());
}
```

the answer i am getting is only the first word of that sentence.
the value is a large sentence I am using the above code inside a function foo and this function foo is called inside a append function inside a ajax call.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
 $("#news").append('<a onclick="foo()">xxx</a><input type="hidden" id="idhere" value="item[0]"');
}
```

Why am i getting only a single word as alert.

Am i doing it wrong

Comment: would you write the complete code and html.

Comment: Hi George, it would be useful to have a view on your html code to see what's your js is supposed to do. You talk about getting only a word out of an entire sentence but non of it is visible in your example.

Comment: typing mistake i have it in my original code

Comment: @GeorgeK you have many inputs with the same id! See my answer!

Comment: @Tony let me check...

Comment: @GeorgeK Sorry, forget about feddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68Q3r/

Answer (score 3):

Well, where is "#idhere"?
There is no element that has this id assigned!

Answer (score 2):

You have not given id `idhere` to element.

Try:

```
$("#news").append('<a onclick="foo()">xxx</a><input type="hidden" value="item[0]" id="idhere"');
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you miss the id in hidden field

```
$("#news").append('<a onclick="foo()">xxx</a><input type="hidden" value="item[0]" id="idhere"');
```

Answer (score 2):

Id should be unique! You use $.each, that means you probably will create many elements with the same id. That's bad.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $("#news").append('<a onclick="foo()">xxx</a><input type="hidden" id="idhere' + i + '"    value="item[0]"');
}
```

Use:

```
function foo(){
  alert($('#idhere0').val());
}
```

Or:

```
var vals = $.map($('input[type="hidden"]'), function(el) {
    return $(el).val();
});
alert(vals.join('\n'));
```